# Nav2, controllers, and Twist commands for ackermann robots

Tags: navigation, ros-humble, nav2

So far, I have been always dealing with Ackermann-based robots and I have had good success using the Nav2 stack (thank you to all the contributors to this awesome stack).

I have always been using the Twist command to drive the robot and my hardware controller interprets `twist.angular.z` as a steering angle. This is conceptually wrong since, I think, the right way to use a Twist command for an Ackermann based robot would be to derive a steering angle from the angular.z  instead of just using it as a steering angle directly.
The problem with this approach is that, especially for non-zero turn radius robots, commands with `twist.angular.z != 0` & `twist.linear.x = 0` are not achievable.

What is the right way to control Ackermann-based robots within the Nav2 stack, using the currently available controllers?

Comment: I think your reasoning here is sound. Perhaps this is better raised as a github issue to get more clarity from the developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `angular.z` field is the body-fixed frame angular velocity, not the steering angle / velocity wrt how Nav2 treats the `Twist` message. That is no different or unique from any other type of robot platform. It sounds like you need to shim the `cmd_vel` topic to the input of your hardware controller to convert body-fixed frame (e.g. base_link) to your steering angle knowing your robot's kinematics.

That's more or less what any and all robots have to do in this case. Its just that differential / omnidirectional kinematics are more trivial. You need to convert the base_link motion into something your motors / motor controllers can understand (e.g. spin at this velocity with this angle).

Comment: yes, you confirmed basically what I already said. But the question remains: how do you (the controller) deal with a angular.z command != 0 and linear.x = 0? I guess a good controller will never generate such command if the turning radius is > 0?

Comment: If you have an ackermann drive vehicle, you should be using an appropriate ackermann drive controller which should be aware of your constraints. E.g. pick the right algorithms for your job.